# in which i have been using amazon s3 bucket to save and retrieve images

Tags: magento-1.9, aws, s3

Here is the Thing.

I have been using the Amazon s3 bucket for storing my media Files Uploaded In Magento. and recently my access was changed from public to private to download the Media File. When trying to download I am getting the below error.

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>53B0FB011615A</RequestId>
<HostId>
R7P3oExhw2uIVZRRMIvyZ+mL00fdO/z1KCyACsekDJVtjYzFXU7P6NgPkpy5wTUBVpVk=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

Can Someone Help me how to download the media files when the owner access was even private? Help must be appreciated.

Comment: From where are you trying to access it, browser?

Comment: yes, I am integrating the amazon s3 to Magento, so I run that in the browser usually. @YashPatadia

Comment: in S3 you can try write access as private and read access as public if that doesn't affect your requirement

Comment: How can I write, is there any code or configurations settings. @YashPatadia

Comment: In case if you want to try the paid extension
https://magecomp.com/magento-amazon-s3.html